# While installing Ubuntu I have formatted my hard drive. Do I need to create partitions for my hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

[image]

If yes, then how should I do this?

Comment: Do you want a dual boot (keep Windows OS just add ubuntu as optional OS on boot up) ?   or stand alone ubuntu install where its the only OS ?

Comment: my only OS is ubuntu

Comment: have you already completed installation? If so, what makes you think you need to create partitions?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. What do you want to achieve? Salvage what's of the data that was on your drive previous to the Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1):

No, your screenshot from gparted looks good. If your Ubuntu system works well, fine. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Unless you want to become a guru. Then you should fix it and break it again and again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No - the GUI install script will do this for you if you have no special requirements ... it gives you the option to resize/create partitions yet the default install flow handles these underlying details seamlessly giving you freedom to be oblivious

Comment: indeed, but OP has "formatted their hard drive during installation" so I think they have already installed?